# ASP.NET5 & JWT Bearer Tokens

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I've built an AngularJS app with a WebApi backend, which uses ASP.NET v4. I built the Owin / Identity / authorization / issuing + validation of JWT bearer tokens from the BitOfTech blog: http://bitoftech.net

Now I'm trying to upgrade to ASP.NET v5 and am having difficulty getting the JWT aspect working. Most relevant examples that I can find are riddled with issues as the assemblies have changed so much in the past 12 months. From what I have read, the Authorization Server aspects were not ported to ASP.NET5, so the two main options available are: **IdentityServer** (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) or **OpenIdConnect Server** (https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server).

**IdentityServer** seems to have implemented the whole of the OAuth spec, it's really difficult to know what parts I need to use & how. **OpenIdConnect Server** - I just can't get to work (it uses `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` which I can't even find) and I'm not even sure it's doing what I need it to.

I'm just looking for a replacement from cookies to JWT tokens. If cookies are supported "out of the box", I can't believe they haven't done the same for JWT tokens in this day & age of native apps and JWT prevalence.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: You solved this with OpenIddict right?

Comment: @Jhonattan - yes, I ended up using OpenIddict.